# Resolving or aliasing enum types variable to primitive data types in function template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I'm trying with a function template call in which one of the template parameters is a enumerated type variable that needs to be resolved to a primitive data type. I couldn't get rid of enum because of other considerations.

`USER_FLOAT --> float`, 
`USER_DOUBLE --> double`

I have tried with alias, typedef, using directives for the enum type variables but could find a solution. I am trying to avoid the crude way of checking the template parameter `T` with in the function `to_double_or_float`.

For e.g:

```
template<typename T, typename X>
void
to_double_or_float(void* in_arr, size_t SIZE, size_t arr_index, X* out_arr)
{
        if( T == USER_FLOAT )
       float* tmp_in_arr = static_cast<float*>(in_arr);
        else if(T == USER_DOUBLE )
           double* tmp_in_arr = static_cast<double*>(in_arr); 
        .....

}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum NcompTypes
{
 USER_FLOAT, // needs to resolve to float
 USER_DOUBLE, // needs to resolve to double
 USER_INT // need to resolve to int
};

template<typename T, typename X>
void
to_double_or_float(void* in_arr, size_t SIZE, size_t arr_index, X* out_arr)
{
    T* tmp_in_arr = static_cast<T*>(in_arr);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        out_arr[i] = static_cast<X>(tmp_in_arr[i + arr_index]);
    }
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    float inArr[] = {1.12, 2, 3, 4, 5.23, 6, 7, 8, 34, 43}; // input
    std::vector<double> outArr(10); // output

    to_double_or_float<USER_FLOAT, double>(inArr, 10, 0, outArr.data());
}
```

Would be great, if any one can provide some pointers on this.

Thanks !

Comment: `USER_FLOAT` isn't a type: is a value; maybe with `template <NcompTypes T, typename X>` ?

Comment: Correct. That would pass `USER_FLOAT` as a enum type parameter into the function but that doesn't alias the enum value into native `float` which is desired. I am trying to avoid `template <NcompTypes T, typename X>` which brings me to assign NcompTypes values to native data types explicitly. But instead template `<typename T, typename X>`, is more desired where T has already been resolved from `USER_FLOAT` to `float`